# is there a way to simplify this condition except using loops?

Tags: java

```
        if(robots[0] != null && !robots[0].isStrong()) {
            if(robots[1] != null &&!robots[1].isStrong()) {
                if(robots[2] != null &&!robots[2].isStrong()) {
                        //do something
                }
            }
        }
```

I want to check if all robots are not strong, if they are all not strong ,then do something.
Imagine I have 10 robots ,do I have to write 10 if conditions ?

Comment: Dude!, Have you heard about for loop?

Comment: @Khemraj check the answer below, I dont think foor loop can do this

Comment: @dilix answer could tell you solution using for loop. Isn't it?

Comment: @Khemraj You need to add an extra boolean variable and you can't execute some code directly inside the for loop

Comment: You are a developer man, does this simple logic needs explain? It's use of for loop while holding final value in a boolean.

Comment: You shouldn't do some logic inside the door loop there. Just use the door loop for checking, hold the answer in a boolean and then use that bool in an IF to do whatever you want to do. There is no problem with using a loop, it's equally fast, probably faster and if you add more robots, it wouldn't break everything or you wouldn't have to add more if's

Comment: The stream answer is what im looking for , with for loop , it is still very tedious

Comment: You shouldn't use a stream if you don't event understand the solution with a for loop

Comment: Do you understand what the Stream does then ? ... The For Loop would probably be way easier to fix for you later on. Also a For Loop would be the perfect fit after the lambda in your case... Just saying.

Comment: @TheRealHypo using for loop you have to create a boolean variablel first then check everything, if one condition fails, change the boolean value to false. And if all conditions fulfill, you will need another if condition to excecute more codes. But with the Stream answer below you can do this all in one step, feels like much neat for me.

Comment: Stream is okay if you know what the Stream API is and does, it's a normal coding pattern to do a boolean outside and an extra if in that case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you want to check these conditions are true for every element of your `robots` array, and that you are using Java 8 or above:

```
if (Arrays.stream(robots).allMatch(r -> r!=null && !r.isStrong())) {
    // do whatever
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `Stream.of` and `allMatch`:

```
Robot[] robots = new Robot[10];
// ... fill array
if (Stream.of(robots).allMatch(r -> r != null && ! r.isStrong())) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
boolean allStrong = true;
for (int i = 0; i < robots.length; i++) {
    allStrong = allStrong && robots[i].isStrong();
    if (!allStrong) break; // exit loop because condition is already false
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
boolean allWeak = true;
for (int i = 0; i < robots.length; i++) {
    allWeak = allWeak && !robots[i].isStrong();
    if (!allWeak) break; // exit loop because condition is already true
}
```

Comment: I want to do something when all robots fulfill the conditions, can for loop fulfill this requirement?

Comment: Just check the 'allStrong' boolean in an 'If' after the loop, if that's true all are strong. but I would set allStrong to false first, depending on what is the default value for it.

Comment: He wants to know if all robots are not strong.

Comment: The OP is null-checking every element of the array. You're assuming they're all non-null?

Comment: @khelwood I believe that answer should provide the common idea how to solve the initial problem but not to write copy-paste ready code to be able just insert this code without any knowledge what doest it do.

Answer (score 2):

The whole point of arrays is to (almost) never use explicit indexing (such as `robots[0]`), but to rely on **loop** constructs, like:

```
for (Robot robot : robotArrayOrList) {
  do something about each robot instance
```

Answer (score 1):

Use loop or stream, Stream is much cleaner

**Using for loop**

```
int stupidCountVar = 0;
for (int i=0; i < robots.size(); i++) {

if (robots[i] != null && !robots[i].isStrong()) 
   {
      stupidCountVar++; 
   }
}

if(stupidCountVar==robots.size())
{
   // your code to survive
}
```

**Using Stream to filter data**

```
Stream<String> yourArrayStream = Arrays.stream(robots);
fitRobots = yourArrayStream.filter(robot - > robot!= null && !robot.isStrong())
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**[Edit] ---
Now in your case -**

```
if (yourArrayStream.allMatch(robot -> robot !=null && !robot.isStrong())) {
// your code to survive
}
```

Comment: Your code does something for all the elements where the condition applies, but OP wanted to check whether the condition applies to all elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can check all of them with a loop:

```
boolean myCondition = true;

for(int i= 0; i < robots.length; i++){
  if(robots[i] == null || robots[i].isStrong() ){
    myCondition = false;
  }
}

// so here you know if myCondition is true or false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Streams to filter required items:

```
Predicate<Robot[]> isAllNotStrong = robots -> Optional.of(Arrays.stream(robots)).orElseGet(Stream::empty)
                                                       .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                                                       .noneMatch(Robot::isStrong);
```

Comment: This does not check whether the condition applies to all elements, but instead performs some actions for all elements the condition applies to. Update: Now it checks whether the condition applies to at least one...

Comment: @tobias_k fixed

Comment: Nope. What if all are `null`? You are checking `== null or ! strong`, not `!= null and ! strong`. Big difference.

Comment: Yep, fixed. Actually `null` check is not a scope of the question. As you can see, in the question there is no null check as well

Comment: @oleg.cherednik The OP's conditions require that each element in the array is non-null. Your code skips null elements in the array.

Comment: I did not mean "what if the array is null", but what if all (or in fact just one of) the elements in the array are null? It does not match OP's condition.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a array of robots you can iterate through it with your favorite loop or iterator:

```
for(int i = 0; i < robots.length; i++) {
    if(robots[i] == null || robots[i].isStrong()) return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean notStrong = false;
for (Robot robot : robotArray) {
  if( robot == null || !robots[i].isStrong() ) {
     notStrong = true;
     break;
  }
}
// this avoids running the Loop again and again if the condition already fails
```

Comment: now `notStrong` is true if *any* of the robots is not strong, but OP wanted to check that *no* robot is strong (i.e. all are "weak").